# What is the difference between Ivy's revision and pubrevision attributes on the publish task?

Tags: ivy

Looking at the details of the publish task ([publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/publish.html)), what is the difference between the "revision" attribute and the "pubrevision" attribute?

An example would be a big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice all you'll ever need is the **pubrevision** parameter.

Here's my understanding:

When you invoke the ivy [resolve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) task, the following parameter values get set based on the matching [info](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/info.html) parameters in your [ivy.xml](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html) file.

- organisation
- module
- revision

Couple of issues to bear in mind:

1. The [publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html) can optionally over-ride the ivy file (Can't think of a useful use-case)
2. Only **organisation** and **module** are mandatory in the ivy file. **revision** is likely to be unset.